# Tabla en html y php desde mysql

Tags: php, mysql, table

queria saber como se puede hacer una tabla que en lugar de mostrar los registros de una bbbdd por columnas me los muestre dentro de una misma celda. Tengo en cada registro (legajo, nombre, dni) y quiero poder hacer una tabla en html con 3 columnas y que cada celda me muestra los datos de todo el gristro.
En las imagenes muestro mi codigo el cual lee una bbdd y genera un codigo de barras con el legajo del empleado, pero a su vez quiero que en el mismo codigo aparezca el nombre y otros detalles como se ve en la segunda imagen. No he podido hacerlo de otra forma que esta y no me agrada como queda.
La idea es poder imprimir en pdf, la imagen del resultado es un imprimir como pdf desde el navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor, cambia la imagen donde tienes tu codigo, por texto, de favor.

Comment: Usas alguna librería para pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo solo es cuestion de estilos nada mas, te dejo un ejemplo . Lo que puedes hacer es que en una variable PHP coloques los estilos y asi lo reutilizes en todos los div que va generar tu for ,en la cual ira la informacion como quieres visualizarla segun la informacion dinamica que traes desde la base de datos , porque en una tabla no se puede realizar lo que quieres hacer . Espero que te sirva este ejemplo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  .estliosCajas {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1px;
  }
  
  .celdas {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="estliosCajas">

    <div class="celdas">

      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

    <div class="celdas">

      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

    <div class="celdas">

      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="estliosCajas">

    <div class="celdas">
      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

    <div class="celdas">

      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

    <div class="celdas">

      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="estliosCajas">

    <div class="celdas">
      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

    <div class="celdas">

      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

    <div class="celdas">

      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span>Apellido</span><br>
      <span>Edad</span><br>

    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```